# To analyze some percentage structure, is Breslow-Day any different than Chi2 for contengency table?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, odds-ratio, contingency-tables

I was asked to compare three groups for their percentage structure. Let me explain - there is a categorical variable X with 3 levels: <100, 100-200, > 200 units. That's all I have and I have no access to the full numerical outcome.

The three levels are summarized with N and %. I was asked to compare the % across 3 groups defined by another variable, say, Y, with also 3 levels.

Let's say X is a 3-level stress level measured in Y=3 companies. I need to check if the stress measured and categorized into "low, medium, big" (<100, 100-200, >200) is different across the companies.

Effectively this means a contingency table X*Y = 3x3. I thought the Chi2 will be sufficient. More, I thought the Breslow-Day cannot handle more than 2x2 tables, as odds-ratio is a ratio of TWO values.

But instead I was asked to run the Breslow-Day test. Could anyone tell me, why testing odds-ratio across 3 groups is different from comparing the %A:%B:%C across three groups?

Is Breslow-Day more powerful or meaningful here?

How about the log-linear analysis or simple the chi2 for contingency table? For me this would be ideal approach.

---

This page mentions also one more test, next to Breslow-Day, Tarone: [Correct equation for Breslow-Day statistic in homogeneity test of odds ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212701/correct-equation-for-breslow-day-statistic-in-homogeneity-test-of-odds-ratio)

Again - why not just Chi2?

Comment: *"Let me explain - there is a categorical variable X with 3 groups..."* I don't follow this explanation. You have a variable $X$ but don't you have any other variables? *"The three values are summarized with N and %"* What does it mean to summarize with N and %? *"Effectively this means a contingency table 3x3"* Why do you get a 3x3 contingency table? What are the labels of such table? Could you give an example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too in a hurry... I fixed it. There are 2 varaibles, X and Y, both with 3-levels. The 3 levels of X are summarized with N and % (let's call it a percentage structure of the levels). And the 3 percentages are to be compared across 3 levels of the variable Y. If you need an example, let's say X is a 3-level stress level measured in Y=3 companies. I need to check if the stress measured and categorized into "low, medium, big" (<100, 100-200, >200) is different across the companies.